# Customized folder when logging to Azure Storage Container

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, trace, azure-webapps

for a multi-tenant app service, I would like to have a web server logging system stored in a storage container. I followed [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) and the logs are saved with the structure
ROOT_FOLDER_NAME_OF_WEB_APP/YEAR_FOLDER/MONTH_FOLDER/DAY_FOLDER/HOUR_FOLDER/random_file_name.log

Then I can write on this file with `System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("If you're seeing this, something bad happened");`

Is there a way to manipulate the creation/usage of the Trace to achieve this structure?
ROOT_FOLDER_NAME_OF_WEB_APP/**TENANT_NAME**/YEAR_FOLDER/MONTH_FOLDER/DAY_FOLDER/HOUR_FOLDER/filename_set_by_me.log

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, because the web app has no notion of tenants, as they are only known within your application. You could use a logging library and use that to create the structure you like.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used Log4Net and I could create the desired structure, but it's stored inside the web app disk space at D:\home\LogFiles\AllMyStructure and not in the storage container

Comment: You need to use or write a Log4Net appender that writes to azure blob storage like this one: https://github.com/Geta/log4net.Azure